# how to underestand "of" in "starting times of half past eight for high-schoolers"?

Tags: meaning

> Gavin Newsom, California’s governor, signed legislation which cuts 2.7m of the state’s schoolchildren some slack, setting a limit on **starting times of half past eight for high-schoolers** and eight o’clock for middle schoolers, in the hope that pupils will benefit from the extra time in bed.

---

How does one understand the meaning of "of" here?

Is it similar to the usage in "fear of dark" which dictionary explains as "introducing the object of the action expressed by the preceding"?

dict link : https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/of?q=of

> 9   used after nouns formed from verbs. The noun after ‘of’ can be
>   either the object or the subject of the action.
>
> the arrival of the police (= they arrive)
>   criticism of the police (= they are criticized)
>   fear of the dark
>   the howling of the wind

Comment: Which dictionary? Please link and attribute.

Comment: added, please check, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; it's the usage shown here:

> **of** preposition (THAT IS/ARE)
>
> *the problem of homelessness*
>
> *a rise of two percent in inflation*
>
> *the skill of negotiating*
>
> *the difficulty of bringing up twins*
>
> *the pain of separation*
>
> *At the age of six she could read a newspaper.*

[[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/of)]

The second example given is perhaps the closest that queried. ' ... a limit ... of half past eight ...'.

CED seems to outperform OALD here in listing different senses.